# Mysql find a value between

Tags: mysql, node.js

Script outputs random value (winning ticket) from 0 to 5000 (in this case). Lets take 3001. I need a query to take a row where `id = 4`, because it has the winning ticket. How can I do it?

More info:

```
id 1 has tickets from 0 to 1000
id 2 has tickets from 1000 to 2000
id 3 has tickets from 2000 to 3000
id 4 has tickets from 3000 to 3500 <----- The winning ticket
id 5 has tickets from 3500 to 5000
```

Mysql table:

```
+-----------------------+
| id | Userid  | Ticket |
+-----------------------+
| 1  | 1234567 | 1000   | // 0 to 1000
| 2  | 1234567 | 1000   | // 1000 to 2000
| 3  | 1234567 | 1000   | // 2000 to 3000
| 4  | 9876543 | 500    | // 3000 to 3500
| 5  | 1234567 | 1500   | // 3500 to 5000
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: The data sample provided seems not compatible with the requirements .

Comment: According to your table data, there's no winner

Comment: select id from table where Ticket>='winning_ticket' and Ticket<='winning_ticket'

Comment: Thats the problem, I need the query to calculate the winner using that table. As you can see, id 1 has 1000 tickets (0 to 1000), id 2 has 1000 tickets too, but id 1 already got tickets from 0 to 1000, so id 2 now have tickets from 1000 to 2000 and so on.

Comment: In your data structure, you know how many tickets each user have but you have no way to figure out what numbers. You commented it out next to the table but unfortunatly, no mysql query can read those comments (or is it a twisted calculation of `id * ticket` ?).
If using this exact data structure is absolutely required then it's gonna be complex can you confirm my `id * ticket` theory ? I might have a workaround despite the poor structure

Comment: I tried using forEach, and it works, but I need a more efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query work for you :

```
set @winningticket=3001;
set @cstart=0;
SELECT id, Userid, (lastticket-tickets+1) firstticket, lastticket
FROM
(
SELECT id, Userid, Ticket as tickets, (@cstart := @cstart+Ticket) lastticket
FROM mytable
order by id) a
having @winningticket between firstticket and lastticket;
```

I have made the assumption that id=1 has tickets from 1-1000, id=2 has tickets from 1001 to 2000 - rather than the values you give - otherwise ticket 1000 is owned by id=1 AND id=2, 2000 by id=2 AND id=3 etc - if that is incorrect remove the +1 from the calculation for firstticket & the values will match yours.

The inner subquery creates a cumulative total for the final ticket number owned by that id using a user variable.

The outer query calculates the start ticket number - note this cannot be reliably done in the inner query as the first & last ticket numbers both rely on the same user variable & order of evaluation of columns is not guaranteed & use of the same user variable in the select list is advised against if it is modified in any way.

The outer query uses a having clause to select the winning ticket between first & last ticket number.